# How to set up NAT Gateway for static outbound IP in an Azure App Service using Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core Web API, which I plan to deploy as an Azure App Service. The API interacts with Binance, which requires the IP address associated with my API key to be filled in.

After doing some research on static IPs in Azure, I found that I could use NAT Gateway for a static outbound IP, which is what I need for Binance. However, I've been having some difficulty setting it up.

Here is what I did so far.

Questions:

- Can someone verify if I've correctly set up the NAT Gateway for a static outbound IP based on that article https://www.azureblue.io/how-to-use-fix-ips-with-azure-app-service?
  [image]
- I've seen examples where private endpoints are used to route traffic between Azure App Service and Azure SQL Database within the virtual network. Should I consider implementing this in my current setup? Please elaborate.
- Is it advisable to segregate my resources into different subnets (for instance, `prod-eastus-linuxapp-snet` and `prod-eastus-sqlserver-snet`)?
- How do I confirm that it works technically? Theoretically, it should be doing what it should.

```
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-asp"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "S1"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-app"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true # WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-vnet"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "${local.basename}-linuxapp-snet"
  resource_group_name  = module.resource_group.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "example" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "pip" {
  name                = "${local.basename}-pip"
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  location            = var.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "ng" {
  name                    = "${local.basename}-ng"
  resource_group_name     = module.resource_group.name
  location                = var.location
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.ng.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.pip.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to set up NAT Gateway for static outbound IP in an Azure App Service using Terraform.

To achieve this configuration as mentioned in the query, we need to integrate the web app with the app service plan through the NAT gateway.

Here is the complete configuration for the requirement.

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorgvk"
  location = "East US"
}


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "asp" {
  name                = "demock-asp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "demovk-vnet"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet" {
  name                 = "demovk-linuxapp-snet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_nat_gateway" "nat" {
  name                = "demovk-nat"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  //subnets             = [azurerm_subnet.snet.id]
  //public_ip_address   = [azurerm_public_ip.nat_ip.id]
  sku_name                = "Standard"
  idle_timeout_in_minutes = 10
  zones                   = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_nat_gateway_association" "example" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
  nat_gateway_id = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat.id
}

resource "azurerm_nat_gateway_public_ip_association" "association" {
  nat_gateway_id       = azurerm_nat_gateway.nat.id
  public_ip_address_id = azurerm_public_ip.nat_ip.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_linux_web_app.app.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet.id
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "nat_ip" {
  name                = "demovk-nat-ip"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  allocation_method   = "Static"
   sku                 = "Standard"
  zones               = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip_prefix" "example" {
  name                = "demovk-publicIPPrefix"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  prefix_length       = 30
  zones               = ["1"]
}

resource "azurerm_linux_web_app" "app" {
  name                = "dmeovkapp"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  service_plan_id     = azurerm_service_plan.asp.id

  site_config {
    vnet_route_all_enabled = true
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
 
}
```

**Output:**

steps : `terraform_apply`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are `zones = ["1"]`, `identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }` and `azurerm_public_ip_prefix` necessary? Please elaborate

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the differences between mine and yours are, because both of them are working.

Comment: Every module added has its own requirement, however mentioning them in the code depends on your specific requirement
zones = ["1"]: Keep it if you want the NAT gateway to be deployed in Zone 1 for high availability.
identity { type = "SystemAssigned" }: Keep it if your web app needs to interact with other Azure resources using a managed identity.
azurerm_public_ip_prefix: Only keep it if you have specific use cases that require public IP prefixes with certain lengths and associations. 
We can omit these if you don't need those requirements in the functionality of the resource.

Comment: I also found these two links regarding the zones https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/nat-overview#availability-zones and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/nat-gateway/nat-availability-zones#non-zonal

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand what it is used for. Looks like the Public IP Prefix is a range of IP addresses that can be reserved which is unnecessary in my use case, because my idea is to have this web API and one more web API both using the same IP addresses